# In Rails, how to update plugins used in an application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

If I use devise, or any other plugin for that matter, what are the best practises for updating it when its in my rails 3 app?

I know devise allows you to modify things, how will this work?

Answer (score 0):

in rails 3 you should most likely be managing everything through your Gemfile and bundler.  You would update and maintain your gems through bundler. http://gembundler.com/